# Remove extra spaces between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got the output below:

> sports(6 spaces)mourinho keen to tie up long-term de gea deal
>
> opinion(5 spaces)the reality of north korea as a nuclear power

How can I make them become sports(1 space) .... and opinion(1 space)... when I write to a .txt file?

Here is my code:

```
the_frame = pdsql.read_sql_query("SELECT category, title FROM training;", conn)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
print(the_frame)
the_frame = the_frame.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)#tried to remove multiple spaces
base_filename = 'Values.txt'
with open(os.path.join(base_filename),'w') as outfile:
    df = pd.DataFrame(the_frame)
    df.to_string(outfile, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Make the output properly formatted monospaced code instead of variable spaced content formatting. And paste in the actual output.

Comment: That way you don't need to day "(6 spaces)"

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't have a tab in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is nice, only should be simplify:

Also tested for multiple tabs, it working nice too.

```
the_frame = pdsql.read_sql_query("SELECT category, title FROM training;", conn)
the_frame = the_frame.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
base_filename = 'Values.txt'
the_frame.to_csv(base_filename, index=False, header=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
the_frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['sports      mourinho keen to tie up long-term de gea deal',
          'opinion     the reality of north korea as a nuclear power'],
    'B': list(range(2))
})
print (the_frame)
                                                   A  B
0  sports      mourinho keen to tie up long-term ...  0
1  opinion     the reality of north korea as a nu...  1

the_frame = the_frame.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
print (the_frame)
                                                   A  B
0  sports mourinho keen to tie up long-term de ge...  0
1  opinion the reality of north korea as a nuclea...  1
```

EDIT: I believe you need join both columns with space and write output to `file` without `sep` parameter.

```
the_frame = pd.DataFrame({'category': {0: 'sports', 1: 'sports', 2: 'opinion', 3: 'opinion', 4: 'opinion'}, 'title': {0: 'mourinho keen to tie up long-term de gea deal', 1: 'suarez fires barcelona nine clear in sociedad fightback', 2: 'the reality of north korea as a nuclear power', 3: 'the real fire fury', 4: 'opposition and dr mahathir'}} )
print (the_frame)
  category                                              title
0   sports      mourinho keen to tie up long-term de gea deal
1   sports  suarez fires barcelona nine clear in sociedad ...
2  opinion      the reality of north korea as a nuclear power
3  opinion                                 the real fire fury
4  opinion                         opposition and dr mahathir

the_frame = the_frame['category'] + ' ' + the_frame['title']
print (the_frame)
0    sports mourinho keen to tie up long-term de ge...
1    sports suarez fires barcelona nine clear in so...
2    opinion the reality of north korea as a nuclea...
3                           opinion the real fire fury
4                   opinion opposition and dr mahathir
dtype: object

base_filename = 'Values.txt'
the_frame.to_csv(base_filename, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Hi I try to use your code but seems like it will become: sport,mourinho... and I tried to modify a bit to df.to_csv(base_filename, sep=" ", index=False, header=False), the result will become: sport "mourinho...." I don't want the double quotation either. Do you have any idea how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: OK, what is `print (the_frame.head().to_dict())` ? There is multiple columns?

Comment: Hmm yea, here you go:
{'category': {0: 'sports', 1: 'sports', 2: 'opinion', 3: 'opinion', 4: 'opinion'}, 'title': {0: 'mourinho keen to tie up long-term de gea deal', 1: 'suarez fires barcelona nine clear in sociedad fightback', 2: 'the reality of north korea as a nuclear power', 3: 'the real fire fury', 4: 'opposition and dr mahathir'}}

Comment: I understnad now, you need join both columns ad write to file.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you so much. However, I'm using the_frame.to_string instead of to_csv as I'm not sure why I will get double quotation again for my certain inputs: eg. "world magnitude-5.1 quake hits 40 miles from batangas, philippines -usgs" It's fixed when I used to_string. Your answer helps a lot. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You are welcome! to your last comment question, do you remove `sep=' '` ?

Comment: Yes, I removed it, write only: the_frame.to_csv(base_filename, index=False, header=False)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following instead of

```
the_frame = the_frame.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
#use the below syntax


the_frame = the_frame.str.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)# this will remove multiple whitespaces .
```

Comment: `.str.replace` working with Series, not with DataFrame.